# How shall I pass a newline character to a command in a script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script, which concatenate its arguments by a given separator

```
#! /bin/bash   

d="$1";
shift;

echo -n "$1";
shift;
printf "%s" "${@/#/$d}";
```

This is how I use it:

```
$ a=(one two 'three four' five)
$ myscript ' *** '  "${a[@]}" 
one *** two *** three four *** five
```

Now I would like to make a newline as the separator, but that doesn't happen:

```
$ myscript '\n'  "${a[@]}" 
one\ntwo\nthree four\nfive
```

How shall I pass a newline character to the printf command in the script? (I am not looking for rewriting my script, if that is possible).
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$'...'` kind of quotes, if you want the `\n` to be expanded into a newline character:

```
myscript $'\n'  "${a[@]}"
```

Or pass the newline literally inside single or double quotes:

```
myscript '
'  "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks. My bad. I did try the second way (Ctrl-Q Ctrl-J), but it failed because of some other silly mistake of mine.

Comment: Or use `%b`.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#! /bin/bash

d="$1";
shift;

echo -n "$1";
shift;
echo -e "${@/#/$d}";
```

Output:

```
$ ./1.sh ' *** '  "${a[@]}"
one *** two  *** three four  *** five

$ ./1.sh '\n'  "${a[@]}"
one
two
three four
five
```

Comment: But then the `\x` sequences would also be expanded in the arguments to contactenate, and `echo` also adds an extra space between each argument and an extra newline character in the end, none of which is asked for here.